# axis proxy Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

Here is the code of the client class.

```
try {

        //System.getProperties().put("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
        //System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPort", "7575");


        String endpoint = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        Service service = new Service();
        Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
        call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint));
        call.setOperationName("AddSMSList"); // Change this to call

        call.addParameter("validation", XMLType.XSD_STRING,
                ParameterMode.IN); // Define Parameters
        call.addParameter("XML", XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
        call.setReturnType(XMLType.XSD_STRING);
        Object[] obj = new Object[] {
                "POWERU-SMS",
                getXML("13627621277", "testtime", "testtype", "testname",
                        "FAIL") }; // Assign value for the parameters
        for (Object i : obj) {
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }
        String ret = (String) call.invoke(obj); // Call web service
        System.out.println("Result : " + ret);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code itself i think is ok. The problem is the connection. 
The Server is in china. And i use the code in Europe trying to reach the server. 
I have to first start a vpn and after that i need to set up a jump server using putty(tunnel) When these are done i can acess the server via browser(proxy). But the java-client always gets a time out says

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail:
```

Could someone please help me. Ive been working on it for 1 week. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

```
System.getProperties().put("socksProxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.getProperties().put("socksProxyPort", "7575");
```

instead of adding the https proxy i should've add the socks proxy!!!

Comment: I don't have a proxy but get this error. It's a https(443) service, I can run it in with a  .Net code in the same PC

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this on this and found a solution. If you're using Websphere add port 8080 to your virtual host's host aliases. The virtual host bound to the app you're trying to access. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To me you seem to be experiencing a firewall issue and not a code issue, try the following from you command line. First do a telnet serverName port if this fails call your network admin and complete a traceroute with him sitting on the other side and the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

This is a proxy server issue. It will be resolved if you provide the proxy server details in  jboss `standalone.xml` file

`-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy host>-Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy port number>`